# How Do You Conditionally Render SVG Color of Custom React Select Drop Down Indicator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-select, fill

Good Morning,

I have looked everywhere and still can't find an answer and I am hoping some intelligent being can aid me on the search for the solution.

I am trying to change the color of my custom SVG dropdown indicator for its default color, on hover and isMenuOpen/ isFocused.

I currently have a component for the drop down indicator trying to apply the color in there like so:

```
 const CustomDropdownIndicator = (props, state) => {
        const isFocused = state.isFocused;
        const isHovered = state.isHovered;

        const defaultColor = '#5f6368';
        const hoverColor = '#202124';
        const focusedColor = '#1a73e8';

        const color = isFocused ? focusedColor : isHovered ? hoverColor : defaultColor;
            

        return (
            <components.DropdownIndicator {...props} style={{ color }}>
                    <img src={dropDownImageSVG} alt="Dropdown Indicator" />
            </components.DropdownIndicator>
        );
    };
```

I am also trying to apply fill values to it in my customStyles object:

```
const customStyles = {
        //more styles
        dropdownIndicator: (provided, state)=> ({
            ...provided,
            width: '32.5px', // Adjust the width to fit your image
            height: '20px', // Adjust the height to fit your image
            transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : null,
            padding: '0px',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            fill: 'red !important',
        }),
       // morestyles
    }
```

this is what the Select component looks like in my React component return and what I am passing to it:

```
<Select
                    styles={customStyles}
                    onMenuOpen={() => setIsOpen(true)}
                    onMenuClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                    class="flag-drop-down"
                    options={customOptions}
                    components={{ DropdownIndicator: CustomDropdownIndicator}}
                    placeholder={isSelectionMade ? '' : <img
                                                            src={require(`../images/flags/${usersCountryFlagSVG}`)}
                                                            alt="Flag"
                                                            width="24"
                                                            height="16"
                                                        />
                    }
                />
```

If anyone has a solution to this, that would be marvelous as I have tried a lot of things now and it's becoming a little tedious haha...

Thanks in advance!

Jake